# ACL for a network device

Tags: linux, authentication, cgi, acl, access-control

I need to implement ACL based authentication mechanism for a device. This device can be accessed through various interfaces like web pages, TL1 (basically through some command prompt) etc.

I need to keep ACL logic centralized so that request from any interface can be authenticated.

ACL logic would basically check whether the logged in user can perform the operation he is trying to perform. For this I will create groups and add users to these groups. Each group would maintain list of operation allowed under that particular group.

Can someone suggest be the best way to implement this?

Is there any existing software/tool that allows me to achieve this? Any open source project?

I am a C/C++ programmer and a newbie to the ACL concept. Above mentioned module is to be developed for Linux OS. Web interface will be in CGI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are file-system specific ACLs available under Linux, but your requirements seem to go beyond tracking of basic file operations. Authenticating web sessions can be done in numerous ways. Maybe pam (man pam) can help you to identify both console and web users.

Comment: Have you tried [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), I believe it would provide the granularity of security control you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misleading. What you ask, has in most cases nothing to do with the ACLs of the filesystem objects in linux.

I'm assuming your cgi is a single file, written in c++.

You will have to use some local data storage solution. In your place I used sqlite, or some other sql-based solution.

I think, your acl lists - which aren't filesystem-based ACLs - should be stored in your local database.

P.s. Furthermore, I suggest to use at least multithreaded fcgi, big cgi binaries are really highly suboptimal.